# Where to start learning SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I recently started at a new job where I'll be working with Sharepoint 2010 to set up (or actually upgrade) an intranet. Unfortunately, I have no experience with SP2010, and the last time I touched SP2007 (or a virtual server for that matter) was four years ago.

I'll be attending a course soon, but until then I have to make myself useful. I've already managed to install a working Sp2010 server and have played around with some web applications and site collections, and trying to find out how Sharepoint Designer works, but I don't really have an idea what I'm doing or what goals I should set for myself to actually learn useful stuff.

I've also watched some tutorials, but most are really problem-specific (problems I don't have yet) or dive into the code (which I won't, probably).

So.. where to start?

Comment: If you dont have specific problems to solve, then you'll have to just make up some, and start learning. Otherwise it's just poking around which isn't an efficient way to learn.

Comment: Well, I could try and simulate the current intranet, which is running on SP2007, but I don't really have an idea what is what there. What kind of pages are used, what kind of web parts. I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Well, someone finally had the time to explain to me what the difference is between web applications, site collections and sites, what a document library is, how workflows work, etc. Now at least I have an overview, but I can't believe this can't be found online somewhere. Added a bounty in the hope some people do know about these kinds of tutorials :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when i started with SP2010, i began by searching:

- New features in Lists and Document
- Libraries New search capabilities
- DocumentSets (they are very interesting!)
- Office Web Apps (Excel and Word web access)
- A little bit of FAST Search Engine
- Integration with silverlight
- Changes in the object model
- Workflows
- New tools in VS2010

(MSDN, codeplex, codeproject, stackoverflow, and several blogs from Sharepoint MVPs are good places to look for)

I don't know if this would help but that's where I started.. if you need specific help you can find several groups in linkedin.. there are a lots of MVPs helping..

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tips. I hadn't thought of LinkedIn yet, i'll take a look right away. I'm playing around a bit with workflows now, but I'll pick some from your list as well :)

Comment: I forgot workflows! i was playing a little bit too... good luck!

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of great training videos on [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/SharePoint2010Developer/).

Answer (score 3):

Sahil Malik's book is organized as what are the basic things all SharePoint 2010 developers need to know. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-SharePoint-2010-Solutions-Professionals/dp/1430228652/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1283973447&sr=8-1

It is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [video tutorials](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=SharePoint+2010&go=&form=VBREQY&qs=n&sk=&sc=8-15) because:

- They are FREE!
- They give you more context than just reading what to do.
- A quick search will get you specific topics.

Check out [Bing videos on SharePoint 2010](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=SharePoint+2010&go=&form=VBREQY&qs=n&sk=&sc=8-15).  There's lots of great content out there to get you going fast.

Comment: oh wow, that's a lot more videos than I could find on youtube. Thanks, will check them out.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to check out the SharePoint guidance on [codeplex](http://spg.codeplex.com/). It comes with at sample portal application that is explained and with best practices and guidance for creating a SharePoint site. I am sure that this will provider vital information and knowledge for your project.

Kr., Bernd.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I really found some useful stuff there, so if nobody else has anything interesting to say I'll accept this as the correct answer. Just a tip though, looking through your answers to other questions you seem to link to that site a lot. Try not to be spammy or you'll probably get banned.

Comment: Hmm, after taking a second look the initial things that I found turned out to be the only things there. There's some good videos and references, but it still doesn't explain basic stuff to me like the general structure and when to use webs/sites/collections/etc..

Comment: Hi again - I am not quite sure what you mean by I link a lot to that site. It is currently the only link to something on codeplex... For the basic understand I would recommend to play with the SharePoint UI. Create some web applications, site collection, sites and lists. That will give you an idea on what is what.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below link to learn sharepoint. It contains sharepoint tutorial videos and all.

http://www.fastsharepoint.com/

Comment: It's not providing a lot of real interesting info though. I only found  three SP2010 videos on there..?

Answer (score 1):

Basically i started my sharepoint learning with the following examples:

1. Create a feature to change site title
2. Create a feature to change site theme
3. Create a feature with feature stapling
4. Create a feature that activates another feature
5. Create a site through code
6. Create a list through code
7. Populate a list with data through code
8. Create a lookup column in list through code

These are the basic examples that you can understand what is Sharepoint as a beginner.

Please see the below link for more beginner programs:

http://blog.sharepointhosting.com/Downloads/SharePoint-Tutorials.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Litso install a dev box on you machine and get started.
Try doing some migration from one server to the other.

Comment: I did, but I just have no idea WHERE to get started. I wouldn't know where to start with a migration either, I think that's not something I'll be doing soon. I'm going to have to start with a fresh installation anyway (request by my boss) and inhibit it with whatever is needed based on what my colleagues want/need to do with it.