# Company wants me to learn Sharepoint 2010 development, should I?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am a Asp.Net developer, currently working on Webforms in 3.5.  I do C# now, used to do VB.Net.  I am also a middle tier developer (business layer and data layer) working on refactoring the current code base to use the Service-Repository pattern.

My boss asked me if I would like to start doing Sharepoint development (company is currently upgrading to 2010, so I would assume I would be doing 2010).

I have read on here that it takes a long time to get up to speed with Sharepoint development, and I don't want to be thrown into the fire while still learning and not knowing what I am doing.

Also, any good places to start learning?  I told my boss I would look into it for about a week and get back to them.

Comment: It's always good to have another Microsoft Technology on your CV. If your company will spend the time and resources for you to learn, you may as well accept the opportunity. Plus, saying no to an employer is generally detrimental to your salary and future prospects.

Comment: I'm in the middle of trying to learn sharepoint (not with a technical background though..) and I have a hard time finding good starting points. Also see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3666799/124238

Comment: @Litso - I saw your question.  There weren't a lot of answers, so that kind of made me worry.  I can google and find tutorials, but I was looking for someone with experience in Sharepoint to point me in the right direction (like you are).

Comment: Also might be good time to ask to go to Sharepoint Conference http://www.mssharepointconference.com/Pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend finding out what they anticipate the company's needs are and whether they anticipate that this will become your primary role.  Ask about what projects they have in mind.  (Of course they're going to say a small percentage, and no, you'll be expected to continue with your regular duties...)

It may be helpful to schedule a 'state of the union' meeting a couple months out to realistically assess how much of your life Sharepoint has taken over, and whether someone else should be brought in to help (or take over).

It certainly can't hurt to get another set of skills under your belt.  Having the background that you do will certainly help you be competitive.  If you don't like the work, there's nothing saying that you have to include it in future resumes...

Comment: I really like your answer. I didn't do that and for better or worse, I have been stuck on one SharePoint project and the other.

Comment: Thanks, @Tundey.  New duties can take over your life/job, especially when it's a new technology and/or paradigm...  (Especially if the boss doesn't really know what he wants to do with it!)

Answer (score 7):

Some good links:

- [Get Started on developing on
  SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2010 Advanced Developer
  Training](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint/ff420377.aspx)
- [SharePoint Hands on lab](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c010fc68-b47f-4db6-b8a8-ad4ba33a35c5)
- [SharePoint Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint/default.aspx)
- [SharePoint Foundation Development in
  Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539092.aspx)

Good luck to you

Answer (score 3):

Don't be scared to learn SharePoint. It may seem like a difficult task at first, but if you take it one step at a time you should be ok. In fact, SharePoint is just a (really big) asp.net web application, so all your existing skills come in handy.

Also the fact that MS finally put some good quality project templates for SharePoint development in Visual Studio 2010 makes the learning curve less steep.

There are also some good books available to get you started. If the company wants you to learn SharePoint, I suppose they would be happy to pay the bill for those. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SharePoint development has a steam learning curve, but from what you already do, you're half way there.
The best place to start is here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/SharePoint2010Developer/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers above. Only thing I would add is, if you had to learn SharePoint, starting with the 2010 version such an advantage over 2007. Especially when you add in Visual Studio 2010...

Regarding where to start, can't hurt learning from the horse's mouth (i.e Microsoft's MSDN sites). Also, be sure to request that your company get you adequate hands-on **developer** training.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to know that [SharePoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) is dedicated to only SharePoint questions.  If you have a non-programming related SharePoint question, or even a programming one, that is a good site to use.