# I need material for learning SharePoint? Can someone send me the link?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am newly appointed to SharePoint. I do know about SharePoint. Can anybody send the link for learning SharePoint for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Also see the answers here: [Where to start learning SharePoint 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3666799/124238)

Answer (score 0):

This book : **Real World SharePoint 2010**

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Real-World-SharePoint-2010-Indispensable-Experiences-from-22-MVPs.productCd-0470597135.html